# HTML/CSS: Overflow hidden not working, how to fix parent div?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Sorry for bad English, English is a second language

I have download a HTML template from
https://html5up.net/fractal

Now I am trying to change background with video playing

```
    <body class="is-preload">
        <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline>
                    <source src="/assets/css/videos/karing1080.mp4">
                </video>
                <div class="content">
                    <h1><a href="#">Widget</a></h1>
                    <p>helper</p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="#" class="button primary icon solid fa-download">Download/p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#one" class="button icon solid fa-chevron-down scrolly">More</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>
```

This is css for video

```
video{
    opacity: .3;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    
    top:0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is overflow does not work and horizontal scroll enabled.

I can tell that parent div is causing error but I do not know what and how to fix it.

I have spent so many hours on fixing it, plz let me know if you need more information for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `overflow: hidden` is an attribute that you apply on a container to hide the overflowing children, you can't just apply it on a children to contain it inside a parent, that's the opposite.

But there's better solution, we don't really need to use `overflow: hidden;`.

Here's CSS that will put your video in the back:

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
}

#header video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

`object-fit: cover` stretches keeping the aspect ratio the entire video to fill given space, which is `100%` `width` and `height` parent container (`#header`).

Also make sure parent of the `video` has `position: relative` - in your code it would be `#header`, like in the code above, otherwise you might be setting the container in relation to unwanted element.

That's all :)

Comment: Actually I have tried something like this, the problem is it is not working either. If you try with the 'fractal' template above, the video-container div's width cannot be fixed to 100%

Comment: Please make sure you're following all the steps 1:1, I did check before posting and it is working. Try copying my code, if it still doesn't work - try hosting your example somewhere.

Comment: holy, actually I tried with min-height and min-width. It works fine, thanks a lot.

Comment: May I ask if why using min-height and min-width does not work?

Comment: @SnoopFrog add   `  z-index: -1 `  on `#video-container`

Comment: @dev.skas that wouldn't work as the `#header` has background on it. It would show the video behind that background.

Comment: @mmd I'm not entirely sure why `min-height` overrides it, possibly an element lower inherits it which forces the video to keep aspect ratio even though we put `cover` on it. Can't really find the other reason myself but maybe a more experienced person could give you a better answer.

Comment: I also edited my message to provide a solution without the container, I don't know why I haven't noticed that it's not actually necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have `position: absolute` working, the parent container needs a styling with `position: relative`. Try that and maybe give the parent container `header` also `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: The problem is, if you try above template, the code is way to complex. Even I fix the header container, it still does not work.